# Process is stuck while invoking a function from Hyperledger fabric test network

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

I already installed chaincode on test network now I am trying to invoke this function addNewPatients(its logic is given below) but only curser is blinking does not give any response or error
Tried to invoke many times but its same

```
async addNewPatients(ctx, patientName, aadhaar, age, gender, mobileNo, address){
    
    
    const patient = await ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey('hospitalName.patient', [aadhaar]).catch(err => console.log(err));
    if(!patient||patient.length===0){
        const patientCounter = await ctx.stub.getState('patientCounter').catch(err => console.log(err));
        let thisPatientID = 'INPK';

        if (!patientCounter || patientCounter.length === 0) {
        thisPatientID += '000000001'; // Start with "INPK000000001" if no patients exist yet
        } 
        else {
        const counter = parseInt(patientCounter.toString());
        thisPatientID += (counter + 1).toString().padStart(9, "0");
        }
        const patientKey = await ctx.stub.createCompositeKey('hospitalName.patient', [thisPatientID, aadhaar])
        const patientDetails = {
            patientID: thisPatientID,
            Name: patientName,
            Aadhaar: aadhaar,
            Age: age,
            Gender: gender,
            contactInfo: mobileNo,
            Address : address,
            
        };
        
        await ctx.stub.putState(patientKey, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(patientDetails)));
        await ctx.stub.putState('patientCounter', Buffer.from(thisPatientID.substring(4)));
        return patientDetails;
        
    }
    else{
        throw new Error("This patient with aadhaar"+ aadhaar + "already exists")
}
}
```

I tried many times to re-run but same issue

Comment: Could you please share your input too?